# How to call multi API in ViewModel on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

In my application I should show **5 recyclerview** and fill data from server. 
I have **5 API** for load data, these **APIs** routes such as :

> example.com/api/products/{category_name}

For all categories such as : **Mobile** - **Shirt** - **Shoes** - **Tv** and all categories response is the same .

And I guess his is very bad solution !

I want know can I handle this APIs and responses dynamically? 
For example, call this APIs and response with one fun and LiveData .

And below code in **Fragment** :

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
            delay(500)
            viewModel.callProductData(CATEGORY_MOBILE)

            viewModel.productData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
                it.forEach { data ->
                    Log.e("ProductsList", "Key => ${data.key} --- Value => ${data.value}")
                }
            }
        }
```

When open **logcat** not show any log with this filter : **ProductsList**

How can I it and call all of APIs with one **fun** and **LiveData** ? 
Please help me use best way for this solution .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an ENUM class for categories

```
enum class Categories(val categoryName: String) {
    CAT("Cat"),
    DOG("Dog"),
    HAMSTER("Hamster")
}
```

Then in ViewModel create LiveData variable in API function

```
private val _items = MutableLiveData<Pair<Categories, List<String>>>()
    val items: LiveData<Pair<Categories, List<String>>>
        get() = _items

    fun callApi(category: Categories) {
        val a = category.categoryName
        //call Api
        _items.postValue(Pair(category, listOf()))
    }
```

And in ViewClass observe LiveData

```
viewModel.items.observe(this) {
          when(it.first){
              Categories.CAT ->{}
              Categories.DOG ->{}
              Categories.HAMSTER ->{}
          }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks my friend, I write your codes, but just show me last api data. I call this APIs : `viewModel.callApi(ProductsCategories.MOBILE)
viewModel.callApi(ProductsCategories.SHOES)
viewModel.callApi(ProductsCategories.STATIONERY)` but just show **STATIONERY** data!

Comment: For example, If delete `viewModel.callApi(ProductsCategories.STATIONERY)` from my codes, then jus show **shoes** data . How can I fix it? I want show all of categories data

Comment: I found strange bug, sometime show Mobile and Shoes category data. sometime show Shoes and Stationery data. sometime show one of category data! why?

Comment: Use coroutines for this.